# Postgresql replace string in table from another table

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem with two tables, those used for accounting
First table named tabela1 have a set of symbol and account. The second table is the symbol, the name to be changed in the first table and the record number of the first table.

Tabela1 is a:

```
ID |KNT_S_WN | KNT_S_MA  |
1  |3021-_R  | 3021-_K-_W|
2  |_W-_R    | _Z        |
```

Tabelas is a:

```
ID | SYMBOL  |REP        |   
1  | _R      |7Z45       |
1  | _K      |321-05     |
1  | _W      |490        |
2  | _W      |C1         |
2  | _R      |C17        |   
2  | _Z      |320        |
```

I need this output:

```
ID |KNT_S_WN   | KNT_S_MA       |
1  |3021-7Z45  | 3021-321-05-490|
2  |C1-C17     | 320            |
```

I try this:

```
update tabela set 
knt_s_wn=replace(knt_s_wn, 
(select symbol from tabelas where tabela.id=tabelas.id and  position(tabelas.symbol in knt_s_wn)>0),
(select a from tabelas where tabela.id=tabelas.id and  position(tabelas.symbol in knt_s_wn)>0))
```

If I use this expression, if it is not knt_s_wn symbol is deleted (blank).
Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest solution is to replace strings in a loop inside a plpgsql function:

```
create or replace function multireplace(aid int, str text)
returns text language plpgsql as $$
declare
    rec record;
begin
    for rec in
        select *
        from tabelas
        where id = aid
    loop
        str:= replace(str, rec.symbol, rec.rep);
    end loop;
    return str;
end $$;
```

[Test it here.](http://rextester.com/FXIMX61691)

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, which is the simplest, and the simpler the better

Comment: @PrzemysławWawrzycki upvoting and accepting answer is preferred method of expressing appreciation at StackOverflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pure sql solution (ie: without procedural sql) to get:

> I need this output:
>
> ```
> ID |KNT_S_WN   | KNT_S_MA       |
> 1  |3021-7Z45  | 3021-321-05-490|
> 2  |C1-C17     | 320            |
> ```

is below:

```
with recursive t(id, knt_s_wn, knt_s_ma, symbols, reps) as (
    select 
        tabela.id, 
        knt_s_wn, 
        knt_s_ma, 
        array_agg(symbol), 
        array_agg(rep)
    from tabela
    join tabelas on tabelas.id = tabela.id
    group by 1, 2, 3
  union all
    select 
        id, 
        replace(knt_s_wn, symbols[1], reps[1]), 
        replace(knt_s_ma, symbols[1], reps[1]), 
        array_remove(symbols, symbols[1]), 
        array_remove(reps, reps[1])
    from t
    where array_length(symbols, 1) > 0
)
select id, knt_s_wn, knt_s_ma
from t
where symbols = array[]::text[];
```

Comment: The question is inspiring, isn't it? See my [alternative solutions](http://rextester.com/KBBR8436) (cte nearly identical; the aggregate is my favourite).